# can I use owl carousel in angular version 14.2.10?

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

The problem is when i try to do "npm i ngx-owl-carousel-o", It gives me an error saying that something wrong about the angular version. My angular version is 14.2.10. what can I do?

I tried to find whether there is an version of owl carousel that compatible for my angular version but I couldn't find.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It s written in their github... https://github.com/vitalii-andriiovskyi/ngx-owl-carousel-o#readme